# Python question relating to dated values in a csv file

Tags: python

I am loading a data file with dated data into a csv.DictReader

The data looks like this:

```
date,   weight, blood_pressure, sugar_level
1/1/01, 120.1,  100.1,          25.2
2/1/01, 130.1,  102.1,          26.2
3/1/01, 110.1,  120.1,          24.2
4/1/01, 130.1,  130.1,          28.2
5/1/01, 160.1,  104.1,          27.0
6/1/01, 150.5,  100.1,          22.5
7/1/01, 120.2,  129.1,          25.2
... etc...
```

I want to write a function that allows me to pass in the dictionary (read from the csv file), and return the previous value of a column an epoch ago. Since there are no enumerations in Python, I will use enums to 'constrain' the permissible epochs and column names:

The code snippet I have so far looks something like this:

```
import csv;

headers = ['date', 'weight', 'blood_pressure', 'sugar_level']
data = csv.DictReader(csvfile, headers);

epoch_type   = (week_ago, fortnight_ago, month_ago);
column_names = headers[1:];

def function get_previous_value(data, column_name, epoch_name):
  """ Note: data is assumed to be sorted in date ascending order  """
  """ Returns the previous value in the data, using the specified """
  """ column name and epoch type                                  """
```

I would be grateful if someone could show how to implement this function

**[Edit]**
Changed argument name from 'lookback' to 'epoch_name' to aid clarity

Comment: What is lookback in this case? Is this hw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please don't use `;` after commands in python.

```
import datetime
import csv

WEEK = datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
DAY = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
MONTH = datetime.timedelta(days=30)

# read the entire file to memory in a dict keyed by date
data = {}
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        data[datetime.datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d/%m/%y').date()] = row
```

now just query the data:

```
# blood pressure one week ago:
print data[(datetime.datetime.now() - WEEK).date()]['blood_pressure']

# the entire data for two months ago:
print data[(datetime.datetime.now() - 2 * MONTH).date()]
```

As an added bonus, you could use [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)'s [`relativedelta`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454)s to make stuff like *"last friday in last month"*.

---

EDIT: If the file is too big to fit memory, the best solution would be to use a database.

Read the entire csv file to a sqlite database. You could use python to do this, but sqlite can already import csv files to table format on its own, and using it is faster than using python to read and parse the file.

Then you can just query the database:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime

# connect to db
con = sqlite3.connect('myfile.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)

date_i_want = datetime.date(2001, 1, 6)
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data WHERE date = ?', (date_i_want,))
row = cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks for reminding me not to bring my C++ habits to Python programming (re: statement terminators)
 :)

Comment: @nosklo: BTW, are 'weeks' and 'days' reserved words in Python?. This statement had me a bit puzzled: WEEK = datetime.timedelta(weeks=1). I can intuitively understand the other statements with days, but I was expecting to see week=7. Please clarify.

Comment: @morpheous: `weeks` is a valid keyword parameter to the `datetime.timedelta()` object constructor. If one passes `weeks=7`, that would mean 7 weeks or 49 days. Check http://docs.python.org/library/datetime#timedelta-objects

Comment: @nosklo: Thanks for the clarification - I thought as much

Comment: @nosklo: thanks for the added bonus!. At this point, I am asking myself this: "could there be a language more beautiful than Python?" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> epochdict = {'week_ago': 7, 'fortnight_ago': 14, 'month_ago': 30}
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1/1/01', '%m/%d/%y').date() + datetime.timedelta(epochdict['week_ago']) < datetime.date.today()
True
```

Comment: could you please explain the second statement?. There seems to be quite a lot happening there. It looks like you are testing a date to see if it is a week old - but I dont see how this ties into the csv data - unless you are simply demonstrating how to test if a random date ('1/1/01' in your example), is less than 1 week ago?

Comment: What I've given is the hard part, the date handling. The rest is just iterating through the data, although you may want to consider reading it all into memory, or even an in-memory database.